# remove after in last md-tab

Tags: angularjs, css, angular-material

I have tabs like this : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KZoLWp

I want to remove `md-tab::after` in first index , I'm using ng-reapet to make tabs.
tried

`.md-tab:last-child::after{display: none;}`

but seems not working on this element.
any help?

Comment: In first tab or last ?

Comment: @rach8garg I'm using rtl language ,in actual project it's last child

Comment: `.md-tab` is not the *last child* of the containing element (`md-pagination-wrapper`), `md-ink-bar` is. Consider using the *pseudo-class* `:last-of-type` instead, e.g: `md-tab-item:last-of-type::after`

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError worked!

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want to remove the thin line that joins the tabs.

> 1. To remove from first tab:

```
.md-tab:first-child::after {
    content: none
}
```

OR

```
.md-tab:first-of-type::after{
    content: none
}
```

> 2. To remove from last tab:

```
.md-tab:last-of-type::after{
    content: none
}
```

> 3. To remove from any tab:

```
.md-tab:nth-child(1)::after{
    content: none
}  // removes from first tab

.md-tab:nth-child(2)::after{
     content: none
}  // removes from second tab

.md-tab:nth-child(3)::after{
    content: none
}  // removes from third tab
```

Just update the value of `'N'` in the `nth-child(N)`. This approach is somewhat generic and uses the nth-child property of CSS.

> 4. To remove from all tabs:

```
.md-tab::after{content: none}
```

Comment: That's Great !!

Answer (score 0):

thank to @UncaughtTypeError comment.

```
md-tab-item:last-of-type::after
{
    display:none !important;
}
```

worked.